# How can I get the source code from the .ipa file?

Tags: iphone, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to reverse-engineer my iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058203/is-it-possible-to-reverse-engineer-my-iphone-application)

I am building an app for a client and want to send him .ipa's files for every build I create so he can play with the app.

I don't however want him to have access to the source code until he pays me.

Can he get the source code somehow from the ipa file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source-code is compiled into an executable. There is no way to reverse engineer that back to your source-code. There is nothing to worry about.

Comment: So how does Apple know that you are using private APIs when you submit your executable to them for the store?

Comment: @Jamie - They have an analyzer that either scans the binary for particular symbols or runs your application and monitors for any callouts to non-public parts of the frameworks.  The former seems to be more likely, given that people have run into false positives where they coincidentally named a method within their application the same as a private method in one of the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

i just built an ad-hoc .ipa and it definitely included source code.

Comment: Long time has passed but still this might be really life saving for me, what do you mean it is definitely included? How could I extract it?

Comment: I grepped the .ipa for specific source-code, and there it was. However, I can no longer reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible. When an *.ipa* is given to Apple for approval, they may send it back with details regarding a bug, or another concern, with the line number of the file and code sample from that location exposing the bug.