# How can we get source from filename.a file and appname.ipa file in iphone.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipa, .a

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to reverse-engineer my iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058203/is-it-possible-to-reverse-engineer-my-iphone-application)
>   [How can I get the source code from the .ipa file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522229/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-from-the-ipa-file)

Is there any way to fetch out the source code from compiled (.a) file and .ipa file in iphone. In android we can get source code from .apk file then why could we not able to get the source code from .ipa file. There should be any way to fetch out the source code from a compiled file in iphone. 
      I have also get trapped in the situation when any of the api for iphone has got then it contains .a file that is compiled and I would not be able to modify its code. So if any founds the way to find out the source code from compiled file in iphone then please answer this question....! 
    I will very thankful to you.

Comment: I have also mention  .a file not only .ipa file so it is not duplicate

Comment: Decompiling and reverse engineering is legally actionable in many countries (i.e. you can be sued).  I hope you are not asking because you want to steal other peoples' code, because that is what is sounds like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the basic objective of creating a .a file is to hide the source code?

However I have "heard" people disassembling signed binaries, using some specialized tools. [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) is one of them.

I can't help you more on operating the tool, as I myself haven't used it ;)

Answer (score 2):

No You can't fetch code from ipa ...

**.a** file is a static library. A static library is a set of routines, external functions and variables which are resolved in a caller at compile-time and copied into a target application by a compiler, linker, or binder, producing an object file and a stand-alone executable. More on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library)

Comment: There must be any way. If we don't try then really we can't find any solution..//

Comment: @Prince it just doesn't work.  IPA's are signed and sealed binaries, so only their header files and bundled items are accessible.  Any attempts to extract methods will be met with ASM code or Hex.

Comment: We can not get source code even from .a file?

Comment: @Princekumar : .a file is static library...check updated answer