# How to use Xcode to open decrypted IPA contents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a decrypted [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_%28file_extension%29) file. How do I use Xcode to open the contents of this file and make code modifications to it?

Comment: This page can be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334072/decompiling-objective-c-libraries

Comment: Please check this link, It may be helpful for you

http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An IPA is just a zip file containing a "Payload" folder, which in turn contains the app bundle. As such there is no code in an IPA - just the compiled executable. You can unzip it and look in the "Payload" folder, but all you'll see is executable code. You could possibly disassemble the code (don't ask me how - I've never tried such a thing), but if you need to do that I wonder why you don't have access to the source in the first place...

Comment: But, many ipa's contain encrypted code and data segments. You need a jailbroken phone to be able to decrypt this, you need access to the hardware keystorage of the phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the source from an IPA file. It's an executable. See Stack Overflow question
*[Is it possible to reverse-engineer my iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058203/is-it-possible-for-someone-to-reverse-engineer-my-iphone-application)*.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode compiles apps from Objective C to machine code, then they are packaged with all the other resources (images, nibs) into an IPA file. So you can't get it back to source code, only machine code.