# How can I view the source code from an app for iOS

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to reverse-engineer my iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058203/is-it-possible-to-reverse-engineer-my-iphone-application)

I'm was searching for an aplication, or a method to view the source code from games and another apps from App Store.

The apps are compiled? If yes, there's another way?

Comment: Apps are compile objective-C code.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm was searching for an aplication, or a method to view the source
>   code from games and another apps from App Store.

There's only one way: ask the author for a copy of the source code and cross your fingers.

> The apps are compiled? If yes, there's another way?

Yes, iOS apps are compiled, so the source code isn't included. You could [try to decompile](http://code.google.com/p/i386codedump/) the app, but what you get isn't going to be the same as the source code that the author wrote.

Comment: Thank you a lot by the answer. I will try these tips.