# iOS App code recovery

Tags: ios, xcode, reverse-engineering, decompiling, recovery

My notebook has been stolen and some apps I´ve been working on were not backuped (about 2 months of developement).
I have learned my lesson now :(
But my question is: I have those apps on my iPad which I use as a development device. Is there any way how to convert, decompile, extract .h and .m files from those apps? They are under developement and was transfered to the iPad via Xcode. Or is there any way to transfer those apps back to Xcode?

Thanks so much for any tips, I´m really desperate.

Comment: Once they're compiled, your binaries aren't privy to much information. You can use certain utilities to get preliminary information (`class-dump` in particular.)

Comment: No. You can't 'decompile' them they are converted into assembly when built and installed as an IPA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to reverse-engineer my iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058203/is-it-possible-to-reverse-engineer-my-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to see the exact code that you wrote (i.e. variable names, method names, etc. will not be available), but you can decompile the binaries with a tool like http://hopperapp.com/

Disclaimer: I've never used the tool myself, but I have heard good things about it.